# WPF: DockPanel Last Visible Child Fill?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, grid-layout, dockpanel

The behavior I'm looking for is basically that of a DockPanel, I would like the last child to fill the available space. The catch is that I would like it to be the last visible child. In my case I have two views I would like to display side by side.

So far I have tried applying two different styles to a grid, neither seems to work. I also tried using a converter which seemed to work in theory(I was able to return "Auto" using double.NaN), but I wasn't sure how to return a width of "*" from code.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=ccSomeItems}" Value="Collapsed">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeOtherItems.AllOtherItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToVisibilityConverter}}" Value="Collapsed">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl x:Name="ccSomeItems" Content="{Binding SomeItems}" Margin="4" Visibility="{Binding SomeItems.AllItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SomeOtherItems}" Margin="4" Visibility="{Binding SomeOtherItems.AllOtherItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm confused... why are you using a `Grid` instead of a `DockPanel` if you want the behavior of a `DockPanel`? Also, you can use the `GridUnitType.Star` unit type to specify star sizes in code behind, like this: `new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star)`

Comment: I'm using a Grid to produce a behavior that a DockPanel does not contain(to my knowledge). Like I said the catch is that I would like to fill the last **visible** child. I will investigate the GridLength class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run with Rachel's comment and find a solution using a converter.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=SomeItems, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToGridLengthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=SomeOtherItems, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToGridLengthConverter}}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl x:Name="SomeItems" Content="{Binding SomeItems}" Visibility="{Binding SubPackages.AllPackages.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="SomeOtherItems" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SomeOtherItems}" Visibility="{Binding Elements.AllElements.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

And the Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Visibility), typeof(GridLength))]
public class VisibilityToGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Collapsed ? new GridLength(0) : new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution which is to just surround the elements you want to fill the available space with a Grid element. Thus making the grid the last element which always fills the available space. The controls within the grid can have their visibility set to whatever they want.

```
    <DockPanel Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,107,0,0" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286" LastChildFill="True">
  <TextBlock Text="Text block" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
  <Grid>
    <Button Content="Button1" Visibility="Visible" />
    <Button Content="Button2" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but my solution was simply to wrap the last child items in a single StackPanel like such:

```
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/> 
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!-- First item -->
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- Last child variable visibility  -->
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsVisble, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- Also last child variable visiblity -->
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
```